# Display AngularStrap Dropdown Manually - How?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

I am trying to display an [AngularStrap dropdown](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/dropdowns) manually, leveraging the `trigger` configuration on `$dropdownProvider` as such

```
// how dropdown is triggered - click | hover | focus | manual
app.config(function($dropdownProvider) {
    angular.extend($dropdownProvider.defaults, {
        trigger: 'manual'
    });
});
```

`click` `hover` `focus` all work fine, but why not `manual`? I have yet to discover any proof that this offered api configuration option works. How can I do this?

In fact, this issue seems to have been discovered after my original question positing, but is now closed and over a year later I have yet to find a solution still.

Issue: [Documentation on how to use trigger=manual is missing](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/723)

I have stubbed out an example that illustrates where I am struggling with this. To clarify my goal, I want to trigger the dropdown in my `<textarea>` on a keystroke (`ng-model` change). I am looking to get a hold on the dropdown and call a function to manually trigger it without using any of the default trigger options, specifically `trigger: manual`, and in an intuitive way to do so as should be offered according to the api, so the desired solution should not be constrained to any specific trigger - but entirely manual to accommodate many differing usages.

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/nV0iOOl62skHe1lfoRxp?p=preview)

---

```
<textarea ng-model="expression" intellisense></textarea>
```

---

```
app.directive('intellisense', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {
                if(v) {
                  // how do I trigger dropdown here on keystroke (model change)?
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For anyone interested, after digging through the source code, I discovered an attribute on directive `bsDropdown` called `bsShow` with the following implementation.

```
// Visibility binding support
attr.bsShow && scope.$watch(attr.bsShow, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(!dropdown || !angular.isDefined(newValue)) return;
    if(angular.isString(newValue)) newValue = !!newValue.match(/true|,?(dropdown),?/i);
    newValue === true ? dropdown.show() : dropdown.hide();
});
```

This essentially drives the dropdown markup to include this and bind to a `$scope` value as such

```
<textarea id="textdrop" ng-model="expression" intellisense bs-dropdown="dropdown" bs-show="drop"></textarea>
```

Then within my directive I can trigger visibility by modifying `$scope.drop` as bound on `bs-show="drop"`

```
app.directive('intellisense', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {
                if(v) {
                  scope.drop = true; // simple - but works
                } else {
                  scope.drop = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

---

It appears this was documented on a project commit as referenced [here](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/commit/8ba875e429376ccc0426c4e25a725799622e5cf9). The official documentation still makes no mention of this as the time of writing, and given the timeline of this I am surprised the lack of attention this has received.

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lz2NMxR4IHUZt0vARjzA?p=preview) with `trigger: manual`

Comment: @davidkonrad thanks for the positive feedback! It's too bad I forked up a bounty to just end up obsessing over this anyways lol

Answer (score 2):

When I have a dropdown as above and want to trigger it manually, I add an `id` to the element :

```html
<button id="myDropdown" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-animation="am-flip-x" bs-dropdown="dropdown">
    Click to toggle dropdown
</button>
```

and then simply trigger the elements `click()` method :

```js
$scope.dropdown = angular.element("#myDropdown");
...
$scope.dropdown.click();
```

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/v5AuBOiMN6TZCPE4eYk2?p=preview**

This can be combined with [angular-hotkeys](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-hotkeys/) :

```js
hotkeys.bindTo($scope)
    .add({
        combo: '<key-combination>',
        description: '<description>',
        callback: function() {
            $scope.dropdown.click()
        }
    })
```

Comment: Could you craft a plunk for this? I still can not get a manual trigger to fire the drop down. The documentation is totally lacking, and according to [this issue](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/723) It sounds like `manual` shouldn't even be part of the api as of yet if it's this involved

Comment: Also I have made an edit to the question. At this point I am not so much concerned with binding a key configuration -but great suggestion. I simply want to trigger the dropdown somehow

Comment: @salniro See this plnkr -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/v5AuBOiMN6TZCPE4eYk2?p=preview** it opens a dropdown by code as described above 1 sec after pageload.

Comment: This is still not what I am aiming for. This isn't using the `trigger: manual` configuration. I don't want to use a `click`, Ideally, I want to trigger the dropdown on a keystroke in my `<textarea>` example

Comment: @salniro, yes - and you just call $scope.dropdown.click() in your (now deleted) directive, by hotkey or whatever when the desired keystroke occurs.

Comment: I still don't see it. `scope.dropdown.click()` is undefined. I updated my plunker, it's still my directive, the logic fires on keystrokes. How can I trigger it there?

Comment: I also don't want to use `click`. I don't want to see dropdown when I click into textarea, I want to fire it manually, on a keystroke

Comment: If you add `trigger: 'manual'` to that example, it does not work. Please see my example with the `<textarea>`

Comment: You have altered your question so many times than the whole meaning is lost. My answer is an answer completely different to the version of your question above. But I let it stay because some other people for sure would like to know how to show a dropdown manually.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion. I edited my question to address the specific issue of displaying the dropdown using the configuration `trigger: manual`. Your suggestion still includes and relies on `trigger: click`. Imo, the question is far easier to understand now without unnecessary distraction. The question always begged for a solution for `manual` though, which no suggestions addressed.

Comment: Yes, but the element that triggers the dropdown could be 0x0 in spread, have you thought about that? Have an empty <span> or <i> or <b>  inside your element, with no length or height, you are doing your dropdowns from ..

Answer (score 0):

Manually triggering datepickers (or any dropdown) is now much easier with v2.0.4 of ngStrap. For more details, see [this Github comment](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/430#issuecomment-49822765).

Here's [a working plunk to demonstrate](http://plnkr.co/edit/NI3EU4nuYeIPV0TZspi0?p=preview) the datepicker as both a manually-triggered dropdown, and as a manually-triggered inline element.

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="dropdownDatepicker.date" bs-datepicker data-trigger="manual" data-bs-show="dropdownDatepicker.show">
```

(And you really don't even need the `data-trigger="manual"`, so you can leave that off if you want).

As for the intellisense directive, that doesn't sound like the issue here, so I'll leave that to you...

Comment: this is great, but you are answering a different question - the poster asked about dropdowns.

Comment: My answer is valid, I just used a datepicker for the example. Datepickers _are_ dropdowns. It works the exact same way for any dropdown, as shown in the accepted answer, which has the same solution as mine (using `bs-show` or `data-bs-show`).